# Loading based on ID in child routes's components

Tags: angular, angular-routing

## Scenario:

I have routes like:

- `/feature/1/page1`
- `/feature/1/page2`
- `/feature/2/page1`

`/feature` route is handled by `AppRoutingModule` and the rest by `FeaureRoutingModule`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'page1',
        component: Page1Component,
      },
      {
        path: 'page2',
        component: Page2Component,
      }
    ],
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FeatureRoutingModule { }
```

## Question:

Currently I can catch ID parameter only in `LayoutComponent` using `ActivatedRoute`. How do I pass it to child components (pages)? How do I handle the loading requirement (load once and then keep in memory)?

I was thinking about creating state-service shared between layout component and pages. Ideally I would like to inject the resource loaded based on :id parameter to page component.

### What I have now:

So I have created `ModelProviderService` that is shared betweem the LayoutComponent and childpages.

```
@Injectable()
export class ModelProviderService {
  currentModel: Model;
  loadFrom(id: string): Observable<Model>{
     this.httpClient.get<Model>(....).do(model => this.currentModel = model);
  }
}
```

and I call it from LayoutComponent:

```
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private modelProvider: ModelProviderService) {     
  }

  private rouerSubscription: Subscription;
  initialized = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rouerSubscription = this.route.paramMap
      .do(params => this.initialized = false)
      .switchMap(params => this.modelProvider.loadFrom(params.get('id;)))
      .do(() => this.initialized = true, error => { this.initialized = false; alert(error); })
      .subscribe();   
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.rouerSubscription) this.rouerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

However, following code does not reflect changes to the route.

```
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modelProvider: ModelProviderService) { }

  model: Model;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.model = this.modelProvider.currentModel;     
  } 
}
```

How do I refresh model when needed? Is it possible to set Page1Component.model from LayoutComponent rather than subscribing to some events in each Page component?

Answer (score 0):

`ActivatedRoute` has a [parent](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#parent) property which can be used to access the parent `ActivatedRoute`.

As for load cache, it is handled by Angular automatically. Once a module is loaded into Angular via a route request, Angular keeps the JIT compiled module in memory, making subsequent requests faster.

**EDIT**: Caching AJAX requests is not handled by Angular. It'd be recommended to make a cache service for that.

Comment: I was not talking about loading modules, but loading some resources using REST apis